# What is the VB.NET equivalent of the C# readonly keyword?

Tags: vb.net

In C# you can do this to make your member variable immutable:

```
public readonly int y = 5;
```

What is the equivalent "readonly" keyword in VB.NET?

Comment: If you're being forced to use VB.NET, learn about the AndAlso and OrElse keywords as well.

Comment: I'd like to use the OrElse keyword (threat) on my code sometimes, too.

Comment: I wonder... does OrElse threaten the compiler?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Amazingly enough, it's [ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2b2c2ka.aspx?ppud=4)

Comment: Private Const Root_Path as string = "C:\app\data"
Private Readonly Backup_Path As String = IO.path.combine(Root_Path, "\Backup")
That is one of my favorite uses for it :)

Comment: I think what's truly amazing is that it only took me a 30 second google query to determine that.

Comment: Suits me right for not trying it.  I was stuck thinking ReadOnly only applied to properties.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, I kept searching: VB.NET immutable (which was getting me nowhere)

Comment: Sometimes, the best tool for helping you search Google is a thesaurus. :)

Comment: Well, I really had blinders on.  I just "knew" it couldn't be ReadOnly because that was used in the Property declaration, so I was specifically *not* searching for readonly.  :)  Oh well.

Comment: @RyanGates - that's not true.  ReadOnly fields in vb.net can also be set in the constructor and *only* in the constructor (or in the original declaration).

Comment: "amazing is that it only took me a 30 second google query to determine that". Thanks to this question and answer it is now only a 5 second google query.

Comment: @MartinBrown and thus is the purpose of StackOverflow fulfilled. :)