# Private class data design pattern is silly?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm reading [this page](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/private_class_data)

I am confused as to what is wrong with the first example. Why cannot he just add readonly to the declaration of the private fields?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The keyword `readonly` (or its equivalent) is provided in some languages (for example, C# and [VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607221/what-is-the-vb-net-equivalent-of-the-c-readonly-keyword)) but not others.

C++ is an example of an object-oriented language that does not have a keyword stipulating "This can be set at any part of a constructor function, but nowhere else".

Object oriented design patterns are meant to be language neutral: applying to all object-oriented languages. 
It follows from this that some languages might have extra features which make a particular pattern obsolete.

In this instance, the presentation of the pattern appears extra silly because the pattern is introduced, then the example is provided *in C#* which doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

He very well could use `readonly`.  It sounds like he doesn't understand what `readonly` does.  [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> The readonly keyword is a modifier that you can use on fields. When a field declaration includes a readonly modifier, assignments to the fields introduced by the declaration can only occur as part of the declaration or in a constructor in the same class.

You *can* set `readonly` fields in a constructor.  In fact, you would have to -- how else are those fields going to have any meaningful value?